# How to implement "Push to an Existing Site" using ZeroMQ and ClankBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, websocket, zeromq, ratchet

I'm currently using [ClankBundle](https://github.com/JDare/ClankBundle) in my Symfony2 app and need to implement the [Push to an Existing Site](http://socketo.me/docs/push) feature mentioned in the Ratchet documentation. However, I found no clues on how to accomplish this functionality using ClankBundle !

I have successfully implemented the [Topic Handler Setup](https://github.com/JDare/ClankBundle) from the ClankBundle documentation, but need a way to add support for [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/).

Could you please demonstrate (preferably with code) how would one use ZeroMQ with Clankbundle?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround that might be useful to you too.

In my setup I have Periodic service that needs to broadcast new information to topic and I have custom topic handler.

First off inject custom topic handler in periodic service and save all subscribed topics in topic handler, something like this:

```
public function onSubscribe(Conn $conn, $topic)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($topic->getId(), self::$subscribedTopics)) {
        self::$subscribedTopics[$topic->getId()] = $topic;
    }

    $topic->broadcast('connected');
}

public function getSubscribedTopics() {
    return self::$subscribedTopics;
}
```

In periodic fetch those topics and broadcast on them:

```
public function tick()
{
    $subscribedTopics = $this->topic->getSubscribedTopics();

    foreach($subscribedTopics as $subscribedTopic) {
        $subscribedTopic->broadcast('yey');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more the "injecting" part ? I don't get it